# Embed message gif not working in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The bot sends a embed message (with the text and the gif). However, the gif doesn't load at all. Everything seems to be working for the other commands but this particular command is not working. I really don't know, please help me. My code:

```
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
        name: 'hug',
        description: "hug command",
        async execute(message, args, Discord) {
            if (!message.mentions.users.first())
            return message.reply('***please mention someone.***');
        
        let keywords = 'anime hug';
        let url = `https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=${keywords}&key=${process.env.TENORKEY}&contentfilter=low`;
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let json = await response.json();
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * json.results.length);
        
              
                
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF8DC4')
        .setTitle(`*Aww how cute, ${message.author.username} gave ${message.mentions.users.first().username} a hug!*`,)
        
        .setImage(json.results[index].url)

    

        message.channel.send(embed + json.results[index].url)
        }
    }
```

Here's a picture of the message:

[image]

Comment: Try to console.log `json.results[index].url`. Is it a valid URL?

Comment: I've fixed it, i was meant to put `.setImage(json.results[index].media[0].gif.url)`

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

Since you're using Tenor API to  send random GIFs in the embed, the direct links do not support embeds. If you `(console.log)` the GIFs, it shows the direct Tenor link of the GIFs.

**Solution**

You need to fetch the `media` link, changing `.setImage(json.results[index].url` to **`.setImage(json.results[index].media[0].url`** should fix the problem.